# Ubuntu: server is doing nothing, but memory is full

Tags: ubuntu, memory, swap, htop

My server is actually on this state:

[image]

I am executing `htop` as root, so I'd see everything.
Sorting by MEM%, I see al processes under 1%. And this even in tree view).

But what does it mean when memory bar is 100% green and also the swap file is 100% red?

Comment: Linux caches your recent activity as you may return to it. It will release it if needed for new application. Difference between Details screen on RAM and free command
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743649/new-16gb-of-ram-installed-yet-i-see-15-3-on-my-system-why?noredirect=1#comment1106622_743649 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/184217/why-most-people-recommend-to-reduce-swappiness-to-10-20/184221#184221 Linux ate my RAM! -  memory use cache
http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Am I reading the screenshot correctly? You have 16GB RAM and only allocated 511MB of swap? That system has been up for over 150 days, I'm guessing the os is having a WTF moment.

Comment: It's a Linode VPS. Swap is preallocated in a dedicated partiion. As Far As I Know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses available memory for disk caching. It will be freed when applications require it, so you don't have to worry if it is shown as full.

Same thing for swap.  (If you want to do something, you might check whether your swap is too small.)

Here's a useful resource about memory usage and free, used, and cached RAM: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/